# gcc <brace-enclosed initializer list> error on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, gcc

```
static unordered_map<string,RoadType> const road_type_string_map = {
  { "unclassified", RoadType::unclassified },
  { "service", RoadType::service },
  { "residential", RoadType::residential },
  { "tertiary", RoadType::tertiary },
  { "secondary", RoadType::secondary },
  { "primary", RoadType:primary }
};
```

The code above compiles on Ubuntu **20.04**, but on **22.04** I get error:

```
sim.h:276:1: error: could not convert ‘{{"unclassified", unclassified}, {"service", service}, {"residential", residential}, {"tertiary", tertiary}, {"secondary", secondary}, {"primary", primary}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘const std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, RoadType>’
  276 | };
```

makefile uses "g++ -std=c++17  -Wall -g"